# XSL obtain variable from external XML with lists

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'd like to load element from external XML into variable in XSL Template file. I load document to variable with no problems, but I can't find corect way how to find exact node which I need based on value of it's child. The structure of external XML is:

```
<mainNode>
 <node1>
  <nodeList1withManyChilds>
   <nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
    <node2>
     <node3>
      <node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>100</node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>
     </node3>
    </node2>
   </nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
   <nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
    <node2>
     <node3>
      <node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>101</node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>
     </node3>
    </node2>
   </nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
   <nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
    <node2>
     <node3>
      <node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>102</node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy>
     </node3>
    </node2>
   </nodeList2withOnlyOneChild>
  </nodeList1withManyChilds>
 </node1>
</mainNode>
```

I need to select right `<node2>` element and the selection should be based on value of `<node4...>` = 100.

In XSL file I have:

```
<xsl:variable name="firstList" select ="$loadedDoc//mainNode/node1" />
```

and I'm not sure how to assign to other variable the exact `<node2>`, which has child's child with searched value. The list collection makes me problems...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Youfr question is not clear. Do you mean you want to select the `node2` that contains the `node4...` with the value of `100`? With `100` being hard-coded into the stylesheet? -- Note also that your tags do not match `node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy` != `node4withIDvalue`!

Comment: Please check the question now, recently miss quotes. Simple say, I need in XSL template file open XML file, get `node2` value from this loaded XML based on it's child's (list) child value

Answer (score 0):

There's no element in your source XML document named "node", so the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="firstList" select ="$loadedDoc//node/node1" />
```

will be an empty sequence. That's not a good place to start.

In your example there is only one node named `node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy`, so you could select it simply as

```
//node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy
```

But I suspect that's not it's real name, because the end tag doesn't match, and for all we know there are other elements with the same name elsewhere in the document.

Perhaps you want `//node4withIDvalue[. = '100']`

But it's very hard to sure, because the information you have given us is incomplete and inconsistent.

Comment: Excuse me, I re-wrote sample tree badly. Now it is edited and more clear, i hope. Based on your advice, I tried instead of: <xsl:variable name="firstList" select ="$loadedDoc//node/node1" /> (and than some next way how to get right child node) using <xsl:variable name="myNode" select ="$loadedDoc//node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy[. = '100']" /> with no positive result. I'm not sure how to work with this loaded document, as it's not clear for me as -context- in common XSL work. Thank you in advance for getting me one more advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want:

```
<xsl:variable name="var2" select="$loadedDoc//node2[descendant::node4withIDvalue=100]"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I also thought I can use this and shoud be working. But because of some reason, that's not working. When I use `<xsl:variable name="var2" select="$loadedDoc//-requestedNodesName-[some condition to select one node from node list]"/>`, nodes choosen by `requestedNodesName` are not selected. If `requestedNodesName = mainNode or node1` it works. But when I go deep into hierarchy and meet first list `nodeList1withManyChilds`, nothing works for me.

Comment: @black-sabath It worked for me using the exact example you have posted (except my XML has `node4withIDvalue` instead if `node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy`). You can also see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LV2

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the solution for that. As external XML is with declared namespaces, I have worked with them not correct way. Declaring node name incl. namespace was not well idea at all. Yes, I did not mentioned namespaces in example, that showing how insignificant they were for me in that case...

Solution for namespaces is:

```
<xsl:variable name="var" select="$loadedDoc//*[local-name() = 'node4withIDvalueUsedToBeSelectedBy' and . = $varWithFindValue]" />
```

My fault, I did not mentioned example with all important details. Thanks.